# PySpark equivalent of Pandas statements

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a question. I have a Spark dataframe I am cleaning up and in pandas, I would normally use:

`df['cases_since_prev_day'] = df.groupby(['county','state'])['cases'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)`

Is there an equivalent statement I could use in PySpark with aggregation?

**EDIT:** So, the original dataset comes from this table on Github - `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv`

A quick peek looks like:

```
date,county,state,fips,cases,deaths
2020-01-21,Snohomish,Washington,53061,1,0
2020-01-22,Snohomish,Washington,53061,1,0
2020-01-23,Snohomish,Washington,53061,1,0
2020-01-24,Cook,Illinois,17031,1,0
2020-01-24,Snohomish,Washington,53061,1,0
2020-01-25,Orange,California,06059,1,0
2020-01-25,Cook,Illinois,17031,1,0
2020-01-25,Snohomish,Washington,53061,1,0
```

I have used pandas to clean up the dataset before and have yielded it in the form of:

```
date,county,state,fips,cases,deaths,ISO3166_1,ISO3166_2,cases_since_prev_day,deaths_since_prev_day,Last_Update_Date,Last_Reported_Flag
2020-03-19,Abbeville,South Carolina,45001,1,0,US,SC,0,0,2020-10-21 22:34:14.644190,False
```

I want to accomplish the same using PySpark. So far, I have for both code and output:

```
#Data from The New York Times, based on reports from state and local health agencies
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pycountry
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append('../utilities')

from utility_setup import create_spark_session, read_s3_to_dataframes
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from write_to_s3 import _write_dataframe_to_csv

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

#Dataframe - read CSV
bucket = 'covid19datalakesafford'
key = 'us-counties.csv'
spark = create_spark_session('COVID-19 NYT - county cases')
df = read_s3_to_dataframes(spark, bucket, key)
df = df.withColumn("fips",df["fips"].cast('string')).withColumn("ISO3166_1",lit("US"))
#df.state.show(2)

subdivisions = {k.name: k.code.replace("US-", "") for k in pycountry.subdivisions.get(country_code="US")}
mapping_func = lambda x: subdivisions.get(x) 
df = df.withColumn('ISO3166_2',udf(mapping_func)("state"))

#df_2["ISO3166_2"] = df_2["state"].apply(lambda x: subdivisions.get(x))



#Old way using Python alone
#df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv", \
#     dtype={'fips': str})

#df = df.withColumnRenamed("ISO3166_1","US") \
#    .withColumnRenamed("ISO3166_2","state")
#df.show(2)

#subdivision_udf = udf(lambda x: subdivisions.get(x))

#function for applying dictionary terms for subdivisions to column

df = df.sort('county', 'date', 'ISO3166_1', 'ISO3166_2')
df.show(2)

#Equivalent in PySpark for lines below?

#df['cases_since_prev_day'] = df.groupby(['county','state'])['cases'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
#df["Last_Update_Date"] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
#df['Last_Reported_Flag'] = df['date'] == df['date'].max()
```

Current table (top two rows):

```
+----------+---------+--------------+-----+-----+------+---------+---------+
|      date|   county|         state| fips|cases|deaths|ISO3166_1|ISO3166_2|
+----------+---------+--------------+-----+-----+------+---------+---------+
|2020-03-19|Abbeville|South Carolina|45001|    1|     0|       US|       SC|
|2020-03-20|Abbeville|South Carolina|45001|    1|     0|       US|       SC|
+----------+---------+--------------+-----+-----+------+---------+---------+
```

**EDIT 2:** Note that this is for a time series and I anticipate the list growing on a daily basis for COVID-19 cases as they are reported on a daily basis by each county/region within each state. Currently, the number of rows in my table approaches ~950,000 and with Pandas it is slow (takes 9 minutes for completion).

Comment: We  need more information - Please share what is the input and output data looks like in a tabular format

Comment: @dsk I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you (almost) all the way there (I don't having your mapping func, so can't get the two-letter state abbreviations):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# county-level windowing - like in SQL
win = Window().partitionBy('county', 'state').orderBy('date')

# lags and final date
df = df.withColumn('cases_since_prev_day', F.lag('cases').over(win))
df = df.withColumn('deaths_since_prev_day', F.lag('deaths').over(win))
df = df.withColumn('Last_Update_Date', F.last('date').over(win))
```

Comment: thanks! It's a starting point at least for me to work off of!

Comment: if it helped, would you mind upvoting or accepting?

Comment: Hi @ags29, would you happen to know how to do as such in PySpark: data['pendingIncrease'] = data['pending'] - data.groupby(['Province_State'])["pending"].shift(1)

Comment: yes I can write the equivalent in PySpark, will do it a bit later

Comment: ```win = Window().partitionBy('Province_State').orderBy('date')```
```data = data.withColumn('pendingIncrease', F.col('pending') - F.lag('pending').over(win) 
```

Comment: that should do it, but I haven't tested since the `pending` column isn't in the example dataset